# Yet another loop JSON object using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am not able to twist my head into understanding how to get Powershell to loop the entire JSON Structure, it wont' loop the System.Object[]

```
$x = ConvertFrom-Json '{
    "Car companies": {
        "Name of Company": "Ford",
        "Cars": [{
            "Name of car": "Ranger",
            "Config": "Pickup"
        },
        {
            "Name of car": "Puma",
            "Config": "Hatchback"
        }]
     }
 }'

foreach( $rootProperty in @($x.psobject.properties | where-object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}) )    {
    write-host " - '$($rootProperty.Name)' = '$($rootProperty.Value)'"
    foreach( $childProperty in @($rootProperty.Value.psobject.properties ) ) {
        write-host "'$($childProperty.Name)' = '$($childProperty.Value)'"
   }
}
```

Outut I get now is just

```
- 'Brand' = '@{Name of Brand=Ford; Cars=System.Object[]}'
   Name of Brand' = 'Ford'
   Cars' = ' '
```

...as a follop [How to iterate through a unknown JSON data/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808165/how-to-iterate-through-a-unknown-json-data-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You're seeing a bug that unexpectedly string-expands the `Cars` property value's array elements to the *empty string*.

A simple workaround - for display purposes only - is to pipe the property value to `Out-String` to get the usual display representation:

```
"'$($childProperty.Name)' = '$($childProperty.Value | Out-String)'"
```

---

You're seeing a *bug* in how arrays of `[pscustomobject]` instances are stringified (as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.6):

Generally, PowerShell arrays are stringified by joining the stringified element representations with the separator specified in the `$OFS` preference variable, which defaults to a space char.

Normally, `[pscustomobject]` instances have a string representation that *resembles* a hashtable literal (but isn't one); e.g.:

```
PS> $custObj = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar' }; "$custObj"
@{foo=bar}  # string representation that *resembles* a hashtable literal
```

Unexpectedly - and this is the bug - when custom objects are the *elements of an array*, they stringify to the *empty string*, which is what you saw:

```
PS> $custObj = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar' }; $arr = $custObj, $custObj; "[$arr]"
[ ] # !! Bug: custom objects stringified to empty strings, joined with a space
```

This is an indirect manifestation of a long-standing bug reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163): that is, elements of an array being stringified are stringified by calls to their `.ToString()` method, and calling `.ToString()` on custom objects unexpectedly yields the empty string (unlike the string representation you get when you directly reference a single custom object in an expandable string, as shown above).